# how to implement google map5 feature in my application in android

Tags: android

I want to implement a google map5 feature in offline mode, in my application. Can anybody tell me how to implement this?

Comment: You need an internet connection for downloading the map tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Maps 5.0 for Android](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html) offer new shiny functionnalities: offline caching and vector graphics.

But the [Maps External library](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/12/under-hood-of-google-maps-50-for.html) from the Google APIs Add On for Android doesn't yet offer those. They might be available one day but I never read that Google said anything on this subject.